# SQL Command error: "incorrect syntax near AND"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

whats wrong in this query showing error ... incorrect syntax near AND

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim cmd As New Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        Dim con As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(constr)
        Try
            Dim strSql As String = "UPDATE hotels SET city = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND hotel = '" & TextBox2.Text & "' AND location = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' AND price = '" & TextBox4.Text & "' AND category = '" & Rating1.CurrentRating & "' AND short = '" & TextBox6.Text & "' AND details = '" & Editor1.Content & "' WHERE hotelid ='" & Request.QueryString("hotelid") & "'"

            '------------"
            con.Open()
            cmd.Connection = con
            cmd.CommandText = strSql
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally
            cmd.Dispose()
            con.Dispose()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sure you'll get many comments related to this but please be aware of [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Forms_of_the_vulnerability) when concatenating non-validated user input into a SQL command. [Example Result](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Dim strSql As String = "UPDATE hotels SET city = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' , hotel = '" & TextBox2.Text & "' , location = '" & TextBox3.Text & "' , price = '" & TextBox4.Text & "' , category = '" & Rating1.CurrentRating & "' , short = '" & TextBox6.Text & "' , details = '" & Editor1.Content & "' WHERE hotelid ='" & Request.QueryString("hotelid") & "'"
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need all those `AND`s, use commas...

Incidentally

- using `string.Format` or, better still [Parameterised Queries](https://web.archive.org/web/20210512233418/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml) or [Stored Procedures](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/gtomar/storedprocedure12052007003126AM/storedprocedure.aspx) is better than all this fiddly joining of strings.

`Dim strSql As String`
`strSql = "UPDATE hotels SET city = '{0}', hotel = '{1}', location = '{2}', price = '{3}', category = '{4}', short = '{5}', details = '{6}' WHERE hotelid ='{7}'"`

`strSql = String.Format(strSql, ,TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim(), TextBox3.Text.Trim(), TextBox4.Text.Trim(), Rating1.CurrentRating, TextBox6.Text,Editor1.Content,Request.QueryString("hotelid"))`

- Its good practice to call `Trim()` on text values from user-input data. This way you won't end up with pesky spaces in arguments/parameters.

Comment: Yes you're right - trying to do this at work without my boss seeing ;-).  Have corrected it now :-)

Comment: Your boss should actively encourage you to get involved in the wider development culture!

Comment: (Sighs.) I know. He's not impressed with my ever-increasing SO reputation either, whereas I'm becoming obsesseed :-o

Answer (score 0):

You also need validate the input in the textboxes so ppl dont du injection exploits against you.